# Lightning client side sorting

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

```
component.set("v.Accounts", Accounts);
```

has the accounts that  I need.

```
<th scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Name" onclick"{!sortbyOpportunityNAme}">Opportunity Name</div>
      </th>
```

I was wondering if there is anyway that I could sort the results on the client side instead of making server calls on click of the column

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Edit

Here's an [updated link](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/66488eb80292c7151f616ebe7d1b0a18) for the code provided below.

---

In Lightning, there's no need to import a library or call out to the server, you can just write your own. Note: I've not tested this, so you may need to tweak it to suit your needs.

```
({
    sortByName: function(component, event, helper) {
        var currentOrder = component.get("v.sortAsc"),
            currentList = component.get("v.records");
        currentOrder = !currentOrder;
        currentList.sort(function(a,b) {
            var t1 = a.Name == b.Name, t2 = a.Name < b.Name;
            return t1? 0: (currentOrder?-1:1)*(t2?1:-1);
        });
        component.set("v.sortAsc", currentOrder);
        component.set("v.records", currentList);
    }
})
```

Your actual click handler needs a minor adjustment as well:

```
onclick="{!c.sortByName}"
```

This code assumes two variables, namely sortAsc, a Boolean, and records, a list of Opportunity records.

To make it more palatable for multiple fields to sort by, you'll want to put this logic into a helper function, then you can replace all the .Name references with a dynamic attribute, like `a[field] < b[field]`.

---

I actually wrote a demo for this. It's not "pretty", but it demonstrates the functionality:

## OpportunityHelper.cls

```
public class OpportunityHelper {
    @AuraEnabled public static Opportunity[] loadOpportunityRecords() {
        return [SELECT Name, Amount FROM Opportunity WHERE Amount <> NULL LIMIT 10];
    }
}
```

## opportunity.app

```
<aura:application controller="OpportunityHelper">
    <aura:attribute type="Opportunity[]" name="records" />
    <aura:attribute type="Boolean" name="sortAsc" />
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="sortField" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <table>
        <thead>
            <td onclick="{!c.sortByName}">Name</td>
            <td onclick="{!c.sortByAmount}">Amount</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!record.Name}</td>
                    <td>{!record.Amount}</td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:application>
```

## opportunityController.js

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var load = component.get("c.loadOpportunityRecords");
        load.setCallback(this, function(result) {
            component.set("v.records", result.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.sortAsc", true);
            helper.sortBy(component, "Name");
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(load);
    },
    sortByName: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.sortBy(component, "Name");
    },
    sortByAmount: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.sortBy(component, "Amount");
    }
})
```

## opportunityHelper.js

```
({
    sortBy: function(component, field) {
        var sortAsc = component.get("v.sortAsc"),
            sortField = component.get("v.sortField"),
            records = component.get("v.records");
        sortAsc = field == sortField? !sortAsc: true;
        records.sort(function(a,b){
            var t1 = a[field] == b[field],
                t2 = a[field] > b[field];
            return t1? 0: (sortAsc?-1:1)*(t2?-1:1);
        });
        component.set("v.sortAsc", sortAsc);
        component.set("v.sortField", field);
        component.set("v.records", records);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't frame my question correctly I use offset over multiple pages is there anyway that I could limit number of records on each page with in the JavaScript?

Comment: @cartman `aura:iteration` doesn't support things like limit/offset, but you could load all of the records into a single variable, then call [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to pull out some of those records into a separate list; you can then iterate over those. The event handlers for next, prev, first, last, etc would simply slice out a chunk of the main record array for display purposes. Sorting, of course, would occur on the master record list, as demonstrated here.

Comment: @cartman I wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/258f9721d3e15d1c5018c180a4a0676d) that demonstrates pagination + sorting client-side. Does this help you?

Comment: @sfdcfox Great gist!  Helped me a lot in a sorting and pagination solution that I needed!  Although the direct link doesn't work anymore.  But you can still find it easy enough.

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox, your solution works. However, I was trying to create a sorting function and pass that function to the `.sort` method like this: `records.sort(this.mySortingFunction)` (the mySortingFunction and the records sorting are both in the helper). Is there a way to do this? Or is the inline sorting the only thing that works?

Comment: @SamuelDev Yes, you should be able to do so, though I didn't only for simplicity. If you're having a problem with your code, might I suggest opening a new question and including your code there? It's pretty hard to address something like this in a comment.

Comment: @sfdcfox, i've created a separate question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217688/lightning-client-side-sorting-using-a-separate-function-not-inline

Comment: Can anyone please explain the code in "opportunityHelper.js", how it works. Just wanted to understand instead of copy paste.

Comment: @ArpitSethi get sortAsc, sortField, and list of records. set sortAsc to true if field changes, toggle sortAsc otherwise (true->false, false->true). call [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) using a function that returns 0 if the two elements are equal, -1 when "a" should appear before "b" in the list, and 1 otherwise. store the changed attributes.