# Sorting function not working

Tags: visualforce, datatable, bootstrap, tablesorter

In this table sorting function is not working for mail room date,the icon is showing but its not functioning.

[image]

This is the code..

```
<th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate">
                        Document Code
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-bare">
                            <svg aria-hidden="true"
                                class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--small"> <use
                                xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0102, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown')}"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort</span>
                        </button>
                    </div></th>
```

Answer (score 4):

SLDS only give you sort icon. They don't actually sort data for you. So you need to write your custom logic to sort the table.

You can use `Order By` clause of SOQL to sort the records.

Comment: how to achieve this,can u show me code snippet

Comment: @SalesforceCoimbatore are you in lightnin or in VF?

Comment: Ligtning @Tushar

Comment: IN Lightning @Tushar

Comment: @SalesforceCoimbatore might help you [Client side sorting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149779/lightning-client-side-sorting)